# Self-answered questions to show off a useful technique?

Tags: discussion

I've seen a couple of examples of self-answered questions used to show a technique that a user discovered or derived.  One of them was advertised up-front as such; the author wrote something like "I'm posting this as a self-answered question in the hope of sharing something useful I created ..."

Is such a practice encouraged / tolerated / discouraged?

Comment: Encouraged. There is even a special self-answer button... Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463 and http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46/131

Comment: By all means, do this. Actually, I think that we should be doing it more.

Comment: Also related: [(834)](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/834/121)